# How to post to Facebook feed with picture?

Tags: php, facebook

I would like to post a picture as feed to my facebook fan page with php sdk v5.
After successfull login I try this method:

```
$data = array(
                     'message'      => 'Blah-blah',
                     'url'          => 'http://www.zzzzz.com/public/foo.jpg'
                 ); 
$res  = $fb->post('/0000000000000000000/feed/',$data,$token);
```

I can see the new message on the wall but there is no picture.
I have tried other ways to assign a picture.

```
$data = array(
                     'message'      => 'Blah-blah',
                     'source'       => $fb>fileToUpload('http://www.zzzzz.com/public/foo.jpg')
                 );
```

The result is the same. The new message shows up on the wall but there is no image.

However, i can post the jpg into photos.

```
$res  = $fb->post('/0000000000000000000/photos/',$data,$token);
```

I login with the following permissions:
email,user_posts,publish_actions,manage_pages,publish_pages,user_photos

Comment: why user_posts, publish_actions, email and user_photos? those are permissions you only need for dealing with a user account, not with a page.

Comment: anyway, the url parameter should be an actual url, not a link to a jpg file. if you want to post photos, use the photos endpoint - you did that already anyway.

Comment: I read in facebook guide to use 'url' array key to assign remote file.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookFile/5.0.0

Comment: yes, for the photos endpoint, NOT for the feed endpoint

Comment: I don't want to post simple photo as feed. I would like to post a link with it. It will be the next step. But now, I can't figure out how to post a single image to feed. I've used a sdk v4 for many years. There was no problem. I have posted jpgs with array key 'picture'. This is no working anymore.